# Radar plot matplotlib - position of yticks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, radar-chart

I have done the radar plot that looks almost how I wanted it to be. However, due to many values on the plot, I would like to amend the alignment of the `ylabels` / `yticks`.

I have no problem in creating `ylabels` / `yticks` with correct values in one line at a given angle, but I want the `ylabels` to be at the corresponding values, rather than have them on the same line. So for each angle, there should be two `ylabels` placed near the corresponding values on the plot. In the picture you can see the values `4.14` and `4.71` correctly placed at the corresponding values. 
Is my idea feasible in Python at all?

That is the code I used:

```
# number of variable
categories=list(data)[0:]
N = len(categories)

# Angles for plotting
angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]

# Initialise
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(40,20))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Draw one axe per variable
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], color='grey', size=16)

# the main problem in my code - placing yticks 'around' the plot
# to be near the corresponding values    
for idx, an in enumerate(angles):
    ax.set_rlabel_position(an) # positioning labels at a given angle
    tick_values = [blue_values[idx],red_values[idx]] # to get the two labels values
    plt.yticks(tick_values, [x.rstrip('.0') for x in list(map(str, tick_values))], color="black", size=16)

plt.ylim(0,max(red_values))

# Add plots
# Plot data
ax.plot(angles, blue_values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
# Fill area
ax.fill(angles, blue_values, 'b', alpha=0.5)

# Plot data
ax.plot(angles, red_values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
# Fill area
ax.fill(angles, red_values, 'r', alpha=0.2)
```

And this is the plot I achieved. As you can see, there are only two labels (of course due to the `for-loop`).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier just to plot the text at the specified coordinates.

```
# number of variable
categories=list(data)[0:]
N = len(categories)

# Angles for plotting
angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]

# Initialise
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(40,20))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Draw one axe per variable
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], color='grey', size=16)

# the main problem in my code - placing yticks 'around' the plot
# to be near the corresponding values

for idx, an in enumerate(angles):
    plt.text(an, red_values[idx], str(red_values[idx]), color="black", size=16)
    plt.text(an, blue_values[idx], str(blue_values[idx]), color="black", size=16)

plt.yticks([])
# plt.yticks(blue_values + red_values, []) # if you want to keep the circles.

plt.ylim(0,max(red_values))

# Add plots
# Plot data
ax.plot(angles, blue_values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
# Fill area
ax.fill(angles, blue_values, 'b', alpha=0.5)

# Plot data
ax.plot(angles, red_values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
# Fill area
ax.fill(angles, red_values, 'r', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]